# How to send attachments with node.js & Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to take a JSON object and attach it to an email as a file attachment so I can send it using the Microsoft Graph API. The email sends fine, but the attachment is lost.

sendIt.js:

```
const { sendMessage } = require('./mailer')

let myObject = {test: {testObject: [{test: 'test'}]}}
let attachment = new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(myObject)).toString('base64')

sendMessage('', 'Test message with JSON', 'message', attachment)
```

.env:

```
#none of your business
```

mailer.js:

```
require('dotenv').config()

const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const O365_TENANT_ID = process.env.O365_TENANT_ID
const O365_CLIENT_ID = process.env.O365_CLIENT_ID
const O365_CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.O365_CLIENT_SECRET
const O365_SENDER_ID = process.env.O365_SENDER_ID
const O365_RECIPIENT_EMAILS = process.env.O365_RECIPIENT_EMAILS

async function sendMessage(to, subject, text, attachment) {
    to = O365_RECIPIENT_EMAILS
    to = to.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    let emails = to.split(";")
    
    let item, addresses = []
    for (e in emails) {
        item = {}
        item.emailAddress = {address: emails[e]}
        addresses.push(item)
    }

    let res = await fetch(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${O365_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token`, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        body: `client_id=${O365_CLIENT_ID}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=${O365_CLIENT_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials`
    })
    let token = await res.json()

    console.log(`Sending message to ${addresses} at ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`)
    console.log(text)
    console.log()

    let message = {
        message: {
            subject: subject,
            body: {
                contentType: 'Text',
                content: text
            },
            toRecipients: addresses
        },
        saveToSentItems: 'true'
    }

    // Send with attachment
    let sendMail = await fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${O365_SENDER_ID}/sendMail`, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `${token.token_type} ${token.access_token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(message),
        attachments: [
            {
                '@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment',
                name: 'attachment.json',
                contentType: 'binary',
                contentBytes: attachment
            }
        ]
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.headers)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))

    await sendMail

}

module.exports = {
    sendMessage
}
```

What am I not doing right?

Comment: On a programming note: either `await` the fetch inside a try/catch, _or_ use `.then().catch()`. Not both. And you already await it, so that final `await sendMail` does nothing, `sendMail` is not a promise. Having said that, are you should you want to call that attachment `binary` when it's base64 string data? Do you even _need_ to base64 encode it? (Looking at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/api-reference/v1.0/includes/snippets/javascript/user-sendmail-with-attachment-javascript-snippets.md, probably not?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I was thinking about the await / try/catch. Appreciate your comments on that. Microsoft's documentation isn't great, particularly for node.js/javascript examples, so I don't know what contentType to pass. Based on my research, I should be using 'base64'. I've tried the contentType of `application/json`.. no luck

Comment: But once you turned it into base64, it's just plain text data, not json. If you want to say `application/json` I'd recommend stringifying it and not then further base64 encoding.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I tried sending the object with  and without base64 encoding with `contentType: 'text/plain'`. The attachment still does not show up--whether or not I stringify it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I got it working. I appreciate your comments...they helped quite a bit. This link gave me some additional needed direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087270/send-mail-with-attachment-microsoft-graph-not-working. I needed `attachments` inside of the message body.